# YoutubeLive API: custom slate image for a scheduled video

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on a desktop live streaming software and I'd like to add my custom thumbnail/image for a scheduled live video (it's known as "slateImage" in youtube's api - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started).

I found in Broadcast.insert [liveBroadcasts#resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource)
contains a parameter called `snippet.thumbnails.(key)`

However it doesn't work for me, the video is with same default slateImage and yes, I remember to enable `contentDetails.startWithSlate = true` there.

Have anybody faced with same?

Answer (score 1):

if you check the documentation [livebroadcasts.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert)

Provide a liveBroadcast resource in the request body. For that resource:

You must specify a value for these properties:

- snippet.title
- snippet.scheduledStartTime
- status.privacyStatus

You can set values for these properties:

- snippet.title
- snippet.description
- snippet.scheduledStartTime
- snippet.scheduledEndTime
- status.privacyStatus
- contentDetails.monitorStream.enableMonitorStream
- contentDetails.monitorStream.broadcastStreamDelayMs
- contentDetails.enableDvr
- contentDetails.enableContentEncryption
- contentDetails.enableEmbed
- contentDetails.recordFromStart
- contentDetails.startWithSlate
- contentDetails.enableClosedCaptions

The same is stated under [livebroadcast.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update) I would say that the `snippet.thumbnails.key` is read only. You are not allowed to write to it though the api.

**contentDetails.startWithSlate**

> This setting indicates whether the broadcast should automatically begin with an in-stream slate when you update the broadcast's status to **live**. After updating the status, you then need to send a [liveCuepoints.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveCuepoints/insert) request that sets the cuepoint's **eventState** to **end** to remove the slate and make your broadcast stream visible to viewers. When you [update a broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update), this property must be set if your API request includes the **contentDetails** part in the **part** parameter value. However, when you [insert a broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert), the property is optional and has a default value of **false**.
>
> Note: This property cannot be updated once the broadcast is in the **testing** or **live** state.

Comment: Yes sure, I thought I was wrong with it because I can set up the thumbnail on my Youtube web page (manual mode). And I don't understand how to use that field "contentDetails.startWithSlate"...

Comment: Remember the Youtube api is very limited there are things that you can do with the web version that can not be done with the api.